# Parsing XをYにと請われた

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-と, passive-voice

> ダンブルドアを大臣にと請われたんだがな、...  (Japanese TL)
> They wanted Dumbledore fer (for) minister ... (original Harry Potter)

The grammar of this sentence confuses me. Is 請う in passive form, or is this honorific? Passive doesn't make any sense to me.

Is ダンブルドア the object of 請う?

I don't understand what に is doing here. 大臣に doesn't seem like a request.

I wonder if all of ダンブルドアを大臣に is the quote and there is an implied する missing.

My final guess is that the unspoken subject is the ministry and the sentence is 'The ministry was asked *to* "make Dumbledore a minister"', where the thing marked by と would be ダンブルドアを大臣にして (or something far more polite) and して is omitted.

Am I close? If not, please help me to untangle what's happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think theoretically it can be both passive/respect, but I would read it as passive. So your understanding should be fine

I assume the speaker has some influence over decision of ministers. The sentence says *I was asked to make Dumbledore a minister*.

Or, if the one who asked to make D. a minister is aristocratic/royal or something, it can be understood as *The noble person asked me to make D. a minister*.

---

> I wonder if all of ダンブルドアを大臣に is the quote and there is an implied する missing.

On this point, it is natural to think that there is a verb omitted between 大臣に and と. As you guessed, it can be '大臣にする(ように)と'. と quotes the content of what was asked. (I was asked (to see) *that ...*).

Comment: Thanks. The speaker has no power in government matters at all though, so "I was asked..." and "The noble person asked me..." are unlikely interpretations. Is there a problem with my translation of "the ministry was asked ..."? Does that change anything about the analysis?

Comment: @user3856370 - I believe the subject in the original English ("they") is the ministry. Who the subject of 請われた is (who the ministry asked Dumbledore be minister) is not clear. It could be Hogwarts, which might have had some say over whether or not to let him go.

Comment: @user3856370 Not sure of the whole [context](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Cornelius_Fudge%27s_daily_letters_to_Albus_Dumbledore), but as commented above, the speaker (Hagrid) may feel himself as part of the school and the sentence means *We were asked...*. Or if *they* were considered to be respectable, it could be plain respect れる.